# Django ForeignModels

Tags: python, django

How do I get/set foreign key fields on a model object without touching the database and loading the related object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django actually appends an '_id' to ForeignKey field names and with 'field_name_id' you can get or set the integer id value directly:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(MyOtherModel)

mymodel_instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
# queries database for related object and the result is a MyOtherModel instance
print mymodel_instance.field
# result is simply the integer id value, does not do any query
print mymodel_instance.field_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .select_related() to load up related models as part of the initial query. You can then get/set properties without a database hit.

Remember that to save stuff, you will need to hit the database.

For details on how to use it, try the [documentation](http://www.google.com.au/url?q=http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/%23id4&usg=AFQjCNHYMocKaa7hWAYJQkIenGT3-jLDpA&ei=7JzXS7q0MsyGkAXsp_zEBg&sa=X&oi=section_link&resnum=1&ct=legacy&ved=0CA4QygQ).

Comment: .select_related() will generate a join, which I don't need to do. The foreign key id is already a field in the tuple that represents the object, I just need to get/set that id. I don't need to get/set any fields in the related tuple.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what you has asked: I thought you were asking how to set fields on a related model.